# Calculation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\psi_1(n)}{2^nn^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation, closed-form

**Calculation of** $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\psi_1(n)}{2^nn^2}$$

### My attempt

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\psi_1(n)}{2^n n^2} &= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\psi_1(n)\left(\frac{\log(2)}{2^n n}+\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} x^{n-1}\log(x)dx\right) \\
&= \color{green}{-\log(2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\psi_1(n)}{2^n n}}\color{blue}{-\int_0^{1\over 2}\frac{\log(x)}{1-x}\left(\zeta(2)-\text{Li}_2(x) \right)dx }\tag{1}
\end{align*}

I don’t know how to evaluate $$\log(2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\psi_1(n)}{2^n n}$$ and $$-\int_0^{1\over 2}\frac{\log(x)}{1-x}\left(\zeta(2)-\text{Li}_2(x) \right)dx$$

Comment: May I see the deleted answer?

Comment: Which deleted answer?

Comment: Kstargamer said the problem was posted by a user named "will byres," who has since been deleted.

Comment: $\int_0^a \ln(x) \operatorname{Li}_2(x)/(1-x) dx$ is well known and you can find it on this site.

Comment: For a different method, we can use \begin{equation}
\Psi_n(z)=(-1)^{n+1} n!\left(\zeta(n+1)-H_{z-1}^{(n+1)}\right)
\end{equation}